# Previous months names as Leabels (Eg Dec 15 Nov 15 ) in place of new title and new title 2 Labels

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

How can I modify the below code to show Previous months names (current month Jan 16) as Labels (Eg **Dec 15**   **Nov 15** ) in place of the Label **new title** and **new title 2** Labels . I am new to Java Script and Kendo UI
-Philip-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        groupable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true,
                            buttonCount: 5
                        },
                        columns: [{
                            field: "ContactName",
                            title: "Contact Name",
                            width: 200
                        }, {
                            field: "ContactTitle",
                            title: "Contact Title"
                        }, {
                            field: "CompanyName",
                            title: "Company Name"
                        }, {
                            field: "Country",
                            width: 150
                        }]
                    });

                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#grid th[data-field=ContactName] .k-link").html("NewTitle");
                    $("#grid th[data-field=ContactTitle] .k-link").html("NewTitle 2");

                    //Another approach - using the "setOptions" method of the Grid:
                    //$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions({
                    //  columns: [[{
                    //        field: "ContactName",
                    //        title: "NEW NAME",
                    //        width: 200
                    //    }, {
                    //        field: "ContactTitle",
                    //        title: "Contact Title"
                    //    }, {
                    //        field: "CompanyName",
                    //        title: "Company Name"
                    //    }, {
                    //        field: "Country",
                    //        width: 150
                    //    }]]
                    //}, 100);
                  });
                });
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the title text of the grid columns. Check http://dojo.telerik.com/@uygard/oLEZa

Comment: Great Thanks a lot for your answer. It solved my issue.

Comment: One more thing these type of customization where shall I look into ? Kindly advise.